# Alamofire error after adding via Cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I have a Xcode project that is written in Objective-C. But I want to write my new screens in Swift and need the Alamofire framework. I already have Swift files in my project but after trying a few times I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/USERNAME/Developer/APP NAME/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/USERNAME/Developer/APP NAME/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And in the terminal I get the following suggestion:

```
[!] The `APP NAME [Debug]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APP-NAME/Pods-APP-NAME.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `APP NAME [Release]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APP-NAME/Pods-APP-NAME.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I already tried to add the `$(inherited)` to `Library Search Paths` (Build Phases.

My pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'APP-NAME' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Comment: do you have `use_frameworks!` in your podfile?

Comment: yes, see my edit question

Comment: @Ruben any luck on this?

Comment: Try cleaning your derived data, close Xcode, 'pod deintegrate', 'pod clean', 'pod install'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you drag the Alamofire.framework file into your project manually, then link the binary with the framework (target-build phase-link binary with libraries-add Alamofire.framework)

I did this to add most of third party library in swift 2.0, xcode 7.3